# Handlebars template - My sub level links are missing - after using Helper function

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

In my object, I have top level and sub level of the property (links) - I need to add the class names to each of the "`li`"'s in the template, for this I am using the helper function.

But I am not getting the sub level of the links..

Any one help me to get this..

**Here is my object:**

```
var obj = [{
    "name": "home",
    "link": "m1/home.html",
    "sub": [{
        "sname": "s1/home",
        "slink": "s1/home.html"
    }, {
        "sname": "s/home",
        "slink2": "s2/home.html"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "service",
    "link": "m2/service.html",
    "sub": [{
        "sname": "s1/service",
        "slink": "s1/service.html"
    }, {
        "sname": "s/service",
        "slink2": "s2/service.html"
    }]
}]
```

**My Template is here:**

```
<div id="navigate"></div>


<script type="text/handlebars-x-template" id="menu">
    <ul>
        {{#list this}}
           <li class="{{className}}"><a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
            {{#if list.sub}}
                <ul>
                    {{#each this}}
                       <li><a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            {{/if}}
        {{/list}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

and my helper function is here:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("list", function(context, option){

    var output = "";

    for(i=0;i<context.length;i++){

        context[i].className = "class"+i;

        if(context[i]["sub"]){

            for(x=0; x < context[i]["sub"].length;x++){

                context[i]["sub"][x].subClass = "subClass"+x;

                console.log(context[i]["sub"][x]); //printing properly.

            }

        }
        output += option.fn(context[i]); // i am only getting top levle the sub level link is missing..
    }

    return output;

})

var temp = Handlebars.compile($("#menu").html());
var html = $("#navigate").html(temp(obj));
```

I understand my helper function is doing wrong here, any one please correct it and help me.

[jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/knjWb/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper function is fine.  But, your template needs some changes.  You want  `#each this.sub` to iterate over the inner lists.  Also, your member var names were wrong for the inner lists.  And, finally you were changing the names of the sub[x].slink to slink2 for some of the items. http://jsfiddle.net/DKnSU/

```
<script type="text/handlebars-x-template" id="menu">
    <ul>
        {{#list this}}
           <li class="{{className}}"><a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
            {{#if this.sub}}
                <ul>
                    {{#each this.sub}}
                       <li class="{{subClass}}"><a href="{{slink}}">{{sname}}</a></li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            {{/if}}
        {{/list}}
    </ul>
</script>

var obj = [{
    "name": "home",
    "link": "m1/home.html",
    "sub": [{
        "sname": "s1/home",
        "slink": "s1/home.html"
    }, {
        "sname": "s/home",
        "slink": "s2/home.html"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "service",
    "link": "m2/service.html",
    "sub": [{
        "sname": "s1/service",
        "slink": "s1/service.html"
    }, {
        "sname": "s/service",
        "slink": "s2/service.html"
    }]
}]
```